# Rails Associations - How to fetch max value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have 2 associated models as follows:

Bid Model:

```
belongs_to :car_ad
```

CarAd Model:

```
has_many :bids

def max_bidvalue
  bids.max(:bid_value)
end
```

Although I can fetch the all bids specific to a car, when I try to fetch the maximum bid_value I receive an error as follow:

```
mycar = CarAd.find(149)

mycar.bids
+----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+-------------+------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| id | auction_id | car_ad_id | user_id | bid_value | increment... | ip_address  | user_agent | bid_time    | created_at  | updated_at    |
+----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+-------------+------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| 1  | 1          | 149       | 35      | 1100      | 100          | 10.10.10.10 | test       | 2018-06-... | 2018-06-... | 2018-06-01... |
| 2  | 1          | 149       | 36      | 1500      | 400          | 10.10.10.10 | test       | 2018-06-... | 2018-06-... | 2018-06-01... |
| 3  | 1          | 149       | 35      | 1600      | 100          | 10.10.10.10 | test       | 2018-06-... | 2018-06-... | 2018-06-01... |
+----+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+-------------+------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+
3 rows in set

 mycar.bids.max(:bid_value)
      Bid Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "bids".* FROM "bids" WHERE "bids"."car_ad_id" = $1  [["car_ad_id", 149]]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
           12: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
           11: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
           10: from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
            9: from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
            8: from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
            7: from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
            6: from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
            5: from (irb):14
            4: from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:99:in `method_missing'
            3: from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:132:in `method_missing'
            2: from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:132:in `public_send'
            1: from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:132:in `max'
    TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)
```

I will appreciate if you can help me to understand the problem here, and how I can solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`maximum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-maximum) instead of `max`

```
mycar.bids.maximum(:bid_value)
```